# Apache - changing admin email address shown in error messages

Tags: apache-2.4, errordocument

I would like to change the email address shown on my error pages - eg, from 500 Internal Server Error:

> ...Please contact the server administrator at *change@this.com* to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error...

I would like to be able to change the email address used in the template to something different.  Where is the email address used in the error page changed?

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these are controlled by the `ServerSignature` directive. It's quite a simple one, so the documentation itself should be sufficient: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serversignature

Some are controled by the `ServerAdmin` directive, which is just an email address

In answer to the comment below, you would need to create your own error pages and map to them with the `ErrorDocument` directive, then you can put whatever email addresses you like in them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, it's appreciated.  I was wondering if there was a way to change the email in individual error pages?  Are there templates for the error pages within Apache that can be altered?  I've tried to find out what I can, but all solutions I have found look to using the .htaccess on individual sites to point to alternative error pages.  I'm not trying to do that, I want to change the default Apache error pages server-wide.

Comment: @memrat That is also described in the Apache documentation, at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html . I strongly suggest that you go read some of the documentation there; you will find the answers to a lot of your questions.